# Insert new line if different number appears in a column

Tags: linux, bash

I have a column

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

I would like to insert a blank line when the value in the column changes:

```
1
1
1
                <- blank line
2
2
2
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using awk:

```
awk -v i=1 'NR>1 && $i!=p { print "" }{ p=$i } 1' file
```

On any line after the first, if value of the "i"th column is different to the previous value, print a blank line. Always set the value of `p`. The `1` at the end evaluates to true, which means that awk prints the line. `i` can be set to the column number of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

`while read L; do [[ "$L" != "$PL" && "$PL" != "" ]] && echo; echo "$L"; PL="$L"; done < file`

Answer (score 1):

**awk(1)** seems like the obvious answer to this problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { prev = "" }
/./ {
    if (prev != "" && prev != $1) print ""
    print
    prev = $1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with SED:

```
sed '{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1\n\1/;tx;P;s/^.*\n/\n/;P;D;:x;P;D}'
```

The long version with explanations is:

```
sed '{
N   # read second line; (terminate if there are no more lines)
s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1\n\1/ # try to replace two identical lines with themselves
tx  # if replacement succeeded then goto label x
P   # print the first line
s/^.*\n/\n/ # replace first line by empty line
P   # print this empty line
D   # delete empty line and proceed with input
:x  # label x
P   # print first line
D   # delete first line and proceed with input
}'
```

One thing I like about using (GNU) SED (what which is not clear if it is useful to you from your question) is that you can easily apply changes in-place with the -i switch, e.g.

`sed -i '{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1\n\1/;tx;P;s/^.*\n/\n/;P;D;:x;P;D}' FILE`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getline` function in Awk to match the current line against the following line:

```
awk '{f=$1; print; getline}f != $1{print ""}1' file
```